# Parsing total funding out of this JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse the total funding dollar amount out of this JSON file:

http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js

Basically I'd like to add up all the raised_amount's in the file.

This is how I parse the other data and that works (that works!):

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/airbnb.js",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(results){
    var number_of_employees = results.number_of_employees;
    var founded_month = results.founded_month;
    var founded_year = results.founded_year;

    $('#number_of_employees').append(number_of_employees);
    $('#founded').append(founded_month + '/' + founded_year);

}
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `obj` is your JSON object:

```
var totalAmount = 0;
var fr = obj.funding_rounds;
for(var i = 0; i < fr.length; i++){
    totalAmount += fr[i].raised_amount;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8XPKq/

```
// convert the format
// disclaimer: there are better ways to do this!

var currencyTotal;

if(totalAmount > 999999){
    currencyTotal = (totalAmount / 1000000).toFixed(1);
    currencyTotal += "M";
}
else if(totalAmount > 999){
    currencyTotal = (totalAmount / 1000).toFixed(1);
    currencyTotal += "K";
}

alert(totalAmount);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8XPKq/1/

Comment: As a bonus: how would I display the number as a currency? I'd like to turn 1200000 in to $1.2M.